# Getting generic return from Jongo finds

Tags: generics, linkedhashmap, jongo

I have a collection structure mapped on a Java class ( just like jongo does ). One of those objects is a generic class ( T ).

To insert data on the collection I used the annotation *JsonProperty( "property_name" )* and it works pretty charm.

The problem is reading the results of this collection. Jongo returns a LinkedHashMap which, obviously cannot be casted to my custom class.

The question is: **how to map the return to my custom class?**

If I should make a custom mapper, how should I proceed?

Thanks! CYA

Comment: is it a find, findOne operation ?

Comment: Maybe or maybe not. After depper research, I found a solution to this issue. Override the mapper on find query. But then I figured I could simple remap the LinkedHashMap calling a convert method from ObjectMapper. It works pretty good.

But which one is the eager way to 're-map' Jongo Mapping? There are other ways to do?